# SQL - get output parameter value

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures

I am trying to output a value from a select statement, but not sure how to complete this.
I call the procedure passing example values 'mypackage' (package_id) and 117 (total_cost). I need it to output the total_cost parameter as a INT.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [aren1002].[ArenDataGetPackageWithRoomCost]
(
    @room_type as int=NULL,
    @package_id as varchar(30)=NULL,
    @total_cost as INT OUTPUT,
    @sql as varchar(400)
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
SELECT @total_cost AS
    string @sql = 'SELECT ' + @package_id + ' from aren1002.HOLIDAY_ROOM where room_standard_id = ' + @room_type
    exec @sql
END
```

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For **SQL SERVER**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [aren1002].[ArenDataGetPackageWithRoomCost]
(
    @room_type AS INT=NULL,
    @package_id AS VARCHAR(30)=NULL,
    @total_cost AS INT OUTPUT,
    @sql AS VARCHAR(400)
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT @total_cost = ' + @package_id + ' from aren1002.HOLIDAY_ROOM where room_standard_id = ' + @room_type
    sp_executesql @sql, '@total_cost AS INT OUTPUT', @total_cost AS INT OUTPUT
END
```

Comment: This will throw error you need to use Nvarchar when `sp_executesql` is used to execute dynamic sql

Comment: I don't know what is that OP's requirement. But if you are using `sp_executesql` then the variable should be declared as `Nvarchar` else you will get error

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [aren1002].[ArenDataGetPackageWithRoomCost]
(
    @room_type as int=NULL,
    @package_id as varchar(30)=NULL,
    @total_cost as INT OUTPUT,
    @sql as varchar(400)
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    select @sql = 'SELECT @total_cost=' + @package_id + ' from aren1002.HOLIDAY_ROOM 
      where room_standard_id = ' + @room_type
    exec sp_executesql @sql,N'@total_cost INT Output',@total_cost output
END
```